# My computer doesn't recognize the following library: linux/config.h when compiling

Tags: kernel, compiling

I have code written in C and I have included some libraries such as linux/config.h and linux/kernel.h.

Whenever I compile the file, it gives me an error saying `No such file or directory` ?

Is there a certain program I should install first ? How can I solve this error ?

Comment: Are you sure that those files are in your include path for headers?

Comment: No I just downloaded the driver and that is what I got when I compiled the file ? but as you asked I check and all the header files are in directory usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-41/include/linux ?? does this help ??

Comment: Maybe this quick and dirty solution works: Add "-I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-41/include/" to your $CFLAGS when running configure, make, etc (if you have no CFLAGS yet, you can simply write "CFLAGS='-I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-41/include/' make"). This *should* instruct your compiler to look in that folder.

Comment: @Zeyad: I think that your compiler simply has no access to that path. You need to inform your compiler where to seek for this files. Instead of `#include "linux/config.h"` write: `#include "usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-41/include/linux/config.h"`. Does this help?

Comment: @Misery yes it helped it was not able to acess the directory thanks alot

Comment: Ok, so this is a wrong way of solving that problem. But now at leas we know what was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

As the link below explains, somewhere in the 2.6.19 kernel, `linux/config.h` was removed.

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/removal-of-include-linux-config-h-file-in-2-6-19-kernel-506363/

Answer (score 1):

If instead of

```
#include "linux/config.h"
```

writing:

```
#include "usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-41/include/linux/config.h"
```

helps, it means that your compiler doesn't know where to look for include files.

If you are using makefile or command-line compilation then [this page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html) will explain what was happening. Othwerise, if you are using some IDE like Eclipse or Code::Blocks, than you need to find project opsions and add include file directries.

Regards,
Misery